# Tune queryset.get for working without DoesNotExist exception in model's Manager

Tags: django, django-models

I have for two similar models with one common Manager, that returns queryset for current logged user. I want User_Places.current_user.get(place=XXX) returns existing User_Place() object or empty User_Places(), when DoesNotExist exception raised. How is it possible? CurrentUserManager doesn't know anything about User_Places and User_Projects models, if I'm right?

I just don't want to write always:

```
try:
    places = User_Places.current_user.get(place=XXX)
except:
    places = User_Places()
```

Code of my models:

```
class User_Places(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    current_user = CurrentUserManager()

class User_Projects(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    current_user = CurrentUserManager()

class CurrentUserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        user = threadlocals.get_current_user()
        qs = super(CurrentUserManager, self).get_query_set()
        if user:
            qs = qs.filter(user=user)
        return qs

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            object = super(CurrentUserManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            object = ????????????????????????
        return object
```

Comment: What does UserProjects have to do with anything?  Why does UserProjects reference UserManager at all?

Comment: Answer for second question: CurrentUserManager lets to get UserProjects and UserPlaces objects specially for current logged user. And I didn't understand first question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809210/django-manager-chaining). There is self.model() inside Manager class:

```
class CurrentUserManager(models.Manager):
    ....
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            object = super(CurrentUserManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            object = self.model(**kwargs)
        return object
```