# Django - specify which model manager Django admin should use

Tags: python, django

I've created a custom Manager for a Django model which returns a QuerySet holding a subset of objects.all(). I need this to be the model's default Manager, since I am also creating a custom tag which will retrieve content from any model (specified by an argument), and needs to use the default Manager for the specified model. All that works fine, except - Django Admin is ALSO using the default Manager for this particular model, which means that not all model instances appear in the admin.

The Django docs don't help:

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (in
>   the order in which they're defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets this first Manager defined in a class as the "default" Manager, and several parts of Django (**though not the admin application**) will use that Manager exclusively for that model.
>   [(Django Managers documentation)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)

The admin isn't supposed to use the default Manager, but it seems to be in my case. Note that I have also explicitly add the default Manager `objects`:

```
subset = CustomManager() # the default manager
objects = models.Manager() # the one I want admin to use
```

How can I specify which Manager the admin should use?

Comment: I was also tripped up by the section you highlighted in the admin docs. It's one of the few times I've found the django docs to be ambiguous.

Comment: Strange. Looking at the latest Django source, it looks as though the admin _does_ use the default manager.

Comment: @Michael the admin has used the default manager since at least Django 1.0. The issue here is more of a documentation bug, which was fixed https://github.com/django/django/commit/f7814cdfe6c3b6d87bb8afdcc5c27ee2e92a6a62#docs/topics/db/managers.txt

Comment: @ChrisLawlor Good point. Thanks for the reference :)

Comment: @Alasdair "It's one of the [sic] few times I've found the django docs to be ambiguous."  LOL.

Comment: @Robert It would have been more accurate if I'd said "it's the only time I've found the docs to be ambiguous". It's five years since I wrote that comment, and I still think the Django docs are excellent. Contributers really care about writing good docs, not just landing new features. This particular issue was fixed in 2010.

Comment: @Alasdair, with all due respect, I can only partially agree with you.  While I appreciate the contributors' documentation efforts, if I were to liken a document to a person's portrait, too often I find that rather than provide a portrait, they only provide the outline of someone's head. I know that's a weird analogy but it fits.  But then I'm a relative Django "newbie" so my needs are probably much different than yours.  Cheers.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can choose the manager by overriding the `queryset` method in your ModelAdmin subclass.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    # use our manager, rather than the default one
    qs = self.model.objects.get_queryset()

    # we need this from the superclass method
    ordering = self.ordering or () # otherwise we might try to *None, which is bad ;)
    if ordering:
        qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
    return qs
```

Comment: They renamed the method to `get_queryset` in Django 1.6. The old name is now [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).

Comment: To clarify, Telofy's comment applies to both `queryset()` and `get_query_set()`. [Django 1.6 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#get-query-set-and-similar-methods-renamed-to-get-queryset)

Answer (score 12):

Updated code:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    """
    Returns a QuerySet of all model instances that can be edited by the
    admin site. This is used by changelist_view.
    """
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
    # TODO: this should be handled by some parameter to the ChangeList.
    ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
    if ordering:
        qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
    return qs
```

_default_manager can be replaced...

Comment: on Django 1.7.7 to get it to work I had to replace ```_default_manager``` by ```_base_manager```

Answer (score 5):

The order in which you define your managers matters. Admin takes the first manager defined on the model.

So if you do like this:

```
subset = CustomManager() # the default manager
objects = models.Manager() # the one I want admin to use
```

the default manager will be `subset`

and if you do like this:

```
objects = models.Manager() # the default manager
subset = CustomManager() # your own manager
```

then the default manager will be `objects`.

Answer (score 1):

As we expect `objects` to be the sole manager, the admin will use `manager` in `self.Admin.manager`.

From the ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4754 opened by troy.simpson

```
class filterManager(models.Manager):
  def get_query_set(self):
    return super(filterManager, self).get_query_set().filter(name='troy')

class Blah(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(maxlength=100)
  objects = filterManager()
  class Admin:
    manager = filterManager()
```

Tested with Django 1.11

Comment: This doesn't work - the Admin inner class on a model is a feature that was removed in Django 1.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/1.0-porting-guide/#replace-class-admin-with-admin-py . You'd need to instead make your `ModelAdmin.get_queryset()` method add the `filter()` call.