# How to show database in django-admin using filters by default?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need to filter database by default every time that I see it (when I save changes or when I open database first time).
Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: My answer answers what I think you're asking - you'll need to clarify your question if it doesn't answer what you meant to ask.

Comment: I have a table. And one of the fields names "processed" (boolean). And I don't want to see rows that already "processed" by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with custom [custom Managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

Say you have a class called `Book`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And you want the admin pages for book objects to only show books by Roald Dahl, then you can add a custom manager:

```
class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(DahlBookManager, self).get_query_set().filter(author='Roald Dahl')

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager()
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager()
```

Then you just need to specify that your `ModelAdmin` should use the `dahl_objects` manager, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545067/django-specify-which-model-manager-django-admin-should-use).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
    return super(DahlBookManager, self).get_query_set().filter(processed=False)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField('book',max_length=1000,null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True, blank=True)
    processed = models.BooleanField('Done',)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.book_name)

    def url1(self):
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (self._url, self.url)
    site_url1.allow_tags = True

    class Admin:
    pass

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'books'

    objects = models.Manager()
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager()
```

here is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mybooks.booksdb.models import Book
from django import forms

admin.autodiscover()

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self,request):
        qs=self.model.objects.get_query_set()
        ordering = self.ordering or ()      
        if ordering:
            qs=qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
....
```

No filter by default. Where is my miss?

Comment: To use the DahlBookManager in the admin, set `qs=self.model.dahl_objects.get_query_set()` in the `queryset` method.