# Changing django default admin history functionality

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am building a Django application on top of an existing database that already has "audit-type" triggers on the tables to log changes to the records.  I want to do two things:

1. Display this information when the "history" button is clicked
2. Disable the function functionality where adding/editing a model object tries to create a records in "django_admin_log" - remember, the table has a trigger on it that is updating a different table.

How can I best accomplish these two goals?

Note: I'm using Python 2.6.5 with Django 1.3.1 and PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: why not log it twice in two tables?

Comment: @uvasal Thanks for the comment.  I guess I could.  But, that feels like the easy way out.  I would like to see how hard it would be to "do it right" and only log things once.  Please don't take that as a criticism though.

Comment: Well IMHO spending any time on something as trivial as that is a waste of time. If you have a lot of users, I would create a trigger or a cronjob that deletes the data in the table

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution could be disabling the LogEntryManager by [overriding the queryset method in your ModelAdmin subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545067/django-specify-which-model-manager-django-admin-should-use). Then you could map the history url's to your custom admin log app.